# How do I create a list of words from a list of sentences?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

If I have a list of strings, such as:

```
lst =  ['aa bb', 'cc dd', 'cc aa']
```

How can I get this into a list of unique words such as this:

```
['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']
```

using a comprehension? Here's as far as I've gotten, to no avail:

```
wordList = [x.split() for row in lst for x in row]
```

Comment: Maybe just move the words into a set?  Set's contain unique values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach I think is probably this, although not the most efficient.

```
set(' '.join(lst).split())
```

If you really want a list, then just wrap that in a call to `list()`

Answer (score 2):

You want to loop over the split values:

```
wordList = [word for row in lst for word in row.split()]
```

then use a set to make the whole list unique:

```
wordList = list({word for row in lst for word in row.split()})
```

or just use a set and be done with it:

```
wordList = {word for row in lst for word in row.split()}
```

Demo:

```
>>> lst =  ['aa bb', 'cc dd', 'cc aa']
>>> list({word for row in lst for word in row.split()})
['aa', 'cc', 'dd', 'bb']
>>> {word for row in lst for word in row.split()}
set(['aa', 'cc', 'dd', 'bb'])
```

If order matters (the above code returns words in *arbitrary* order, the sorted order is a coincidence by virtue of the implementation details of CPython), use a separate set to track duplicate values:

```
seen = set()
wordList = [word for row in lst for word in row.split() if word not in seen and not seen.add(word)]
```

To illustrate the difference, a better input sample:

```
>>> lst = ['the quick brown fox', 'brown speckled hen', 'the hen and the fox']
>>> seen = set()
>>> [word for row in lst for word in row.split() if word not in seen and not seen.add(word)]
['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'speckled', 'hen', 'and']
>>> {word for row in lst for word in row.split()}
set(['and', 'brown', 'fox', 'speckled', 'quick', 'the', 'hen'])
```

Comment: I know the OP asked for a list, but if you are making a set, there probably isn't a reason to make it a list - it's more likely the OP would be fine with a set.

Comment: @Lattyware: There, added in that a `set()` is the easier option.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [25]: list({y for x in lst for y in x.split()})
Out[25]: ['aa', 'cc', 'dd', 'bb']
```

To keep it order, means remove duplicates from a list, you can refer http://www.peterbe.com/plog/uniqifiers-benchmark.

Comment: Yes. The order not maintained.

Comment: I have asked the OP if order matters or not :)

Comment: Using list comprehensions for side effects is incredibly bad practice.

Comment: Really, `i.append()` in a list comprehension? Why not just use `i = [y for x in lst for y in x.split()]` then? There is nothing in your solution that makes the values unique anyway..

Comment: Yeah, I just wrote it wrong. I tend to make it unique but forget to add the condition.

Comment: Order not being maintained is fine. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

For keeping order, you can do something like:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> lst =  ['aa bb', 'cc dd', 'cc aa']
>>> new = []
>>> for i in lst:
...     new.extend(i.split())
...
>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(new))
['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']
```

Note that using a `set()` is most likely faster, as Martijn has pointed out.